# Import and consume javascript in android activity

Tags: javascript, android, web-services, aes

I am trying to establish a connection between android app and webservice. I am sending the encrypted username and password using AES encryption. But my encrypted username and password do not match with the webservice and responses as false.
Same thing I am doing in website encrypting credential with AES encryption in javascript and validating user with webservice everything works fine. I checked AES output for android defers from javascript output.

Bellow code is used in android to encrypt username and password

```
public class RijndaelCrypt {

public static final String TAG = "EncryptLog2";

private static String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
private static String ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static String DIGEST = "MD5";

private static Cipher _cipher;
private static SecretKey skeySpec;
private static IvParameterSpec _IVParamSpec;

//16-byte private key
private static byte[] IV = MainActivity.key.substring(0,16).getBytes();


/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @password Public key
 */
public RijndaelCrypt(String password) {

    try {

        //Encode digest
        MessageDigest digest;
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(DIGEST);
        skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(digest.digest(password.getBytes()), ALGORITHM);

        //Initialize objects
        _cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        _IVParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "No such algorithm " + ALGORITHM, e);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "No such padding PKCS7", e);
    }
}

/**
 * Encryptor.
 *
 * @return Base64 encrypted text
 * @text String to be encrypted
 */
public String encrypt(byte[] text) {

    byte[] encryptedData;

    try {

        _cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, _IVParamSpec);
        encryptedData = _cipher.doFinal(text);

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key  (invalid encoding, wrong length, uninitialized, etc).", e);
        return null;
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid or inappropriate algorithm parameters for " + ALGORITHM, e);
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "The length of data provided to a block cipher is incorrect", e);
        return null;
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "The input data but the data is not padded properly.", e);
        return null;
    }

    return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT);

}

/**
 * Decryptor.
 *
 * @return decrypted text
 * @text Base64 string to be decrypted
 */
public String decrypt(String text) {

    try {
        _cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, _IVParamSpec);

        byte[] decodedValue = Base64.decode(text.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] decryptedVal = _cipher.doFinal(decodedValue);
        return new String(decryptedVal);


    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key  (invalid encoding, wrong length, uninitialized, etc).", e);
        return null;
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid or inappropriate algorithm parameters for " + ALGORITHM, e);
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "The length of data provided to a block cipher is incorrect", e);
        return null;
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "The input data but the data is not padded properly.", e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

}

Can i use that javascript in android without WebView.
**Note:** webservice is built in .net c#.

Sorry for any grammatical mistake, This is my 1st question on StackOverflow.